# Is it true that different types do different rounding?

Tags: python

When I read images with `cv2.imread` and `PIL.Image.open` it gave different results (I have used old version (Pillow 8.4.0), now it fixed (Pillow >= 9.0.0). So when I read it into a numpy array with default type as `uint8`, the results were different, but when I changed the type to `int16`, the results became the same. So my question is: Is it true that different types do different rounding and why is it so?

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img1 = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('post_5c606e629f934.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
img2 = Image.open('post_5c606e629f934.jpg')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
ax[0].imshow(img1)
ax[0].set_xlabel("cv2.imread")
ax[1].imshow(img2)
ax[1].set_xlabel("PIL.Image.open")
ax[2].imshow(img2 - img1)
ax[2].set_xlabel("difference")
plt.show()
```

Gives following result: [image: uint8]

But if we change the type to `int16` then:

```py
img1 = img1.astype(np.int16)
img2 = np.array(img2, dtype=np.int16)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))
ax[0].imshow(img1)
ax[0].set_xlabel("cv2.imread")
ax[1].imshow(img2)
ax[1].set_xlabel("PIL.Image.open")
ax[2].imshow(img2 - img1)
ax[2].set_xlabel("difference")
plt.show()
```

This gives the following result: [image: int16]

Comment: NB: Original image can be found [here](https://kot-pes.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/post_5c606e629f934.jpg)

Comment: Can you still reproduce this? If so, it would help if you could determine which package causes the differences: `cv2`, `Pillow` or `matplotlib` (or possibly another package, such as `numpy`). I'm pretty sure it's not `Pillow`, since that gives the exact same data when using 8.4.0 or 9.2.0. Please include the output of `python -V` and `python -m pip freeze` for the situation that you used to get the non-black delta image. Add that information to your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If I'd have to answer your question "*Is it true that different types do different rounding?*", I'd say that this is not the case, or at least that you can't draw that conclusion from the code you shared.

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue. To understand what's happening, it's important to look at the facts:

- You read an image using OpenCV (`cv2`).
- You read an image using Pillow (`PIL`).
- You extract those images (implicitly using `numpy`).
- You draw that delta image using `matplotlib`.
- The delta image is not fully black, and seems to indicate a "rounding issue" (not on my setup!).

Based on this facts, I'd say that there is a difference in the way that OpenCV and Pillow read the file. Or possibly there is something strange about the way that numpy handles the images. (You could try to add a line `img2 = numpy.array(img2)` to make sure that `img` and `img2` are of the same type, but on my machine this doesn't make a difference).

You suggested that there is a difference between Pillow version 8.4.0 and version >= 9.0.0, but I do not observe such a difference.

The following Python script can be used to verify the actual image data after being read using OpenCV and/or Pillow:

**image_test.py:**

```py
import hashlib
import sys

import cv2
import PIL.Image
import numpy

print('Python version          : %s' % sys.version)
print('PIL version             : %s' % PIL.__version__)

cv2_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('post_5c606e629f934.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_image = PIL.Image.open('post_5c606e629f934.jpg')

if (numpy.array(pil_image) == cv2_image).all():
    print('Images are the same.')

delta_image = pil_image - cv2_image
if delta_image.min() == delta_image.max() == 0:
    print('Delta image is fully black.')

cv2_image_data = cv2_image.tobytes()
print('With CV2:')
print('- Size of image data    : %d' % len(cv2_image_data))
print('- MD5 hash of image data: %a' % hashlib.md5(cv2_image_data).hexdigest())
pil_image_data = numpy.array(pil_image).tobytes()
print('With PIL:')
print('- Size of image data    : %d' % len(pil_image_data))
print('- MD5 hash of image data: %a' % hashlib.md5(pil_image_data).hexdigest())
```

To test with different Pillow versions (*assuming you use a virtual environment on Windows and the above file is stored as `image_test.py`*), run:

```
python -m pip install Pillow==8.4.0 && python -m image_test.py
python -m pip install Pillow==9.2.0 && python -m image_test.py
```

On my machine, the output is:

```
Python version          : 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
PIL version             : 9.2.0
Images are the same.
Delta image is fully black.
With CV2:
- Size of image data    : 3600288
- MD5 hash of image data: '6cc4a9155c15a061660af28d1ac35807'
With PIL:
- Size of image data    : 3600288
- MD5 hash of image data: '6cc4a9155c15a061660af28d1ac35807'
```

This proves that the image data is exactly the same when read with OpenCV or Pillow. I get the same results using Pillow version 8.4.0.

If you can reproduce a different output than this, you can determine where the image data is different (the MD5 hash helps in determining which images are the same and which are not — images with the same hash have exactly the same image data).

If the images are exactly the same using 8-bit data, they will be exactly the same when converted to 16-bit format. The only thing that is different in your last piece of code is the explicit conversion to a numpy array. So there might be something with the way that numpy deals with PIL images, although I couldn't find a version of numpy that has a different behavior. (Conversion functions from PIL Image to numpy array were added in numpy version 1.1.6, which was in 2008, so I can't imagine you're using a version older than that.)

Comment: side question, is there is an advantage to use MD5 hash instead of comparing the two arrays ? Is it faster ? More accurate ?

Comment: @LittlePanic404, in this case it isn't really necessary, because it doesn't provide much more information. However, if OP can reproduce the original problem, an image/array comparison will only result in `False`, while the MD5 hash will tell us _which_ image is different. Assuming OP uses different software versions and the same image, I expect that only one of the hashes will be different than the hashes in my output.